# Should services fetch its configuration through gateway or directly through Configuration Server?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I recently have learnt and practicing Microservice using Spring technology. I am currently writing a small program that has Eureka Server, Configuration Server, Gateway and Account service. I have all of my services register its instance to Eureka and have my Gateway gets its configuration from Configuration Server. After that, I got some question, should I my Account Service fetch its configuration directly from Configuration Server, or from Gateway because it can be done in both way. I think, if I decide to fetch it through Gateway, it might be better because Gateway is a load balancer, so in case if there are multiple Configuration Servers out there, I don't need to worry if any of them failed or down as Gateway can handle this for me. But, doing so, isn't I put too much weight on Gateway because it need to handle this and another requests. Furthermore, I am not sure and I can't find any information about if there is a way to load balancing Gateway or is it makes sense to do so?

Please advice and explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Only user's requests from UI need to be passed via Gateway. Services should be able to fetch their configuration during startup disregarding whether gateway is online or doesn't exist at all.

Also I'd advise you to avoid registering config service in Discovery (Eureka). I suppose there is no need for your users to send requests to config service.

Along with spring cloud [config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) and [gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) documentation I'd recommend you to get familiar with these 2 books:

- https://www.manning.com/books/enterprise-java-microservices
- https://www.manning.com/books/spring-microservices-in-action